# How to remove a parcel from a larger area?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, vector, clip

New QGIS user here.  I'm trying to clip a large (2000-ac) property boundary with a smaller (500+/-) acre property.  Assuming the larger boundary is the input layer and smaller is the clip layer, my output layer then shows up the exact same 500 acres boundary I'm trying to clip with - which is clearly wrong (the larger tract is not clipped).  Seeing the error, I reversed the input and clip files - switched the 500 acre tract to input and the 2000 acre tract as the clip - and the clip file then shows up as the exact same 500 acre boundary as the first failed clip, again wrong.  WTH is wrong here?  How does the clip boundary not cut the input boundary?

[image: 1:clip attempt w/ 2000 acre input, 500 acre clip]

[image: 2:clip attempt w/ 500 acre input, 2000 acre clip]
[image: 3: image of larger tract (dashed) w/ smaller (shaded) tract I'm trying remove from the larger tract]

Comment: You can add an image by pressing Ctrl+G or by clicking the Image icon in the tool bar. Please edit your question and add the image to add more context to your question.

Comment: Can you try the clip with editing turned off for the WellsFargo layer?

Comment: Hi - I thought that might be the issue, but I turned it off - same problem still occurs

Comment: _"my output layer then shows up the exact same 500 acres boundary I'm trying to clip with"_ - Isn't that what the clip is supposed to do? Or is it a duplicate of the 500 acres layer (ie, same attributes without the attributes from the WellsFargo layer)?

Comment: @SaultDon - I'm getting an exact duplicate of the smaller 500 acre tract vs the area of the 500 acre tract (both images above being the 500 ac tract, duplicated each time regardless of input or clip file source).  This parcel should be removed from the larger 2000 acre tract (which I should've included in the image, its abutting and north of the tract you see in the image), obviously about 4 x the size of this parcel.

Comment: Are you allowed to share those shapes for testing?

Comment: @SaultDon. Added 3rd image. Sure, can share. Never had this issue in Arcmap (of which I was novice user).  Can't see why this wouldn't easily work in QGIS using the clip function

Comment: _"This parcel should be removed from the larger 2000 acre tract"_ I think that's a job for the difference tool instead of clip if you're looking to get a hole or erase the smaller polygon area from the larger polygon.

Comment: @SaultDon Could you please put your comment as an answer to the topic, so that Malamutte can mark it as accepted?

Comment: The distinction with the ArcGIS tool is that, depending on which one you use (Geoprocessing Clip vs Editing Clip), you can select whether the area of intersect is preserved or discarded. GP clip works as you see here - clips a shape down to the input boundary (and if input is larger than to be clipped, no change) which is keep area of intersect. With Edit clip, you can either do that or *discard* the area of intersect and keep the other part aka their difference, which is what you're trying to do. ArcGIS does this with the Erase tool (advanced only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it became clear you were instead trying to remove the overlapping portion of the smaller polygon from the larger polygon.

You should use the "Difference" tool instead of the "Clip" tool.